Possible to create a SearchKit search of FormBuilder forms?
With API4, I can search for afform entities like so:
$afforms = \Civi\Api4\Afform::get(TRUE)
  ->addWhere('name', '=', 'afsearchNoteComments')
  ->setLimit(25)
  ->execute();

But in SearchKit, the afform entity is not available for searching (screenshot from dmaster "Powered by CiviCRM 5.78.alpha1"):

This means I can't create a SearchKit listing of FormBuilder forms.
If this is by design, what's the rationale?
Or, am I just doing it wrong?

You wanna submit a PR to remove the @searchable none annotation from \Civi\Api4\Afform.php. I think it's fine to remove that restriction, as SK is getting more useful for 'meta' searches like this one.

Submitted a PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30994
You can apply patch https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30994.patch
